# Test filename with regular expression

Tags: regex

I am trying to test a filename string with this pattern:

```
^[A-Za-z0-9-_,\s]+[.]{1}[A-Za-z]{3}$
```

I want to ensure there is a three letter extension and allow letters, numbers and these symbols: - _ , \s to precede it but I don't want to have to include all of the letters and characters in the filename. I could just use a * instead of a + but that would match 0 or more which wouldn't be a valid filename.

Here are some examples of how the rule should react:

```
Correct file name.pdf - true
Correct, file name.pdf - true
Correct_file_name.pdf - true
Correctfilename.pdf - true
Incorrect &% file name.pdf - false
Incorrect file name- false
```

It would be great if someone could point me in the right direction.

Thanks

Answer (score 72, accepted):

You could use these expressions instead:

- `\w` - is the same as `[a-zA-Z0-9_]`
- `\d` - is the same as `[0-9]`
- `\.` - is the same as `[.]{1}`

Which would make your regex:

```
^[\w,\s-]+\.[A-Za-z]{3}$
```

Note that a literal dash in a character class must be first or last or escaped (I put it last), but you put it in the middle, which incorrectly becomes a *range*.

Notice that the last [a-zA-Z] can not be replaced by `\w` because `\w` includes the underscore character and digits.

**EDITED:** @tomasz is right! `\w` == `[a-zA-Z0-9_]` (confirmed [here](https://www.regular-expressions.info/shorthand.html)), so I altered my answer to remove the unnecessary `\d` from the first character class.

Comment: `\w` is usually [a-zA-Z0-9_]; that's why I'm not a big fan of the class as you have to remember this specific word definition.

Comment: Fantastic, that works a treat thanks! Can you explain why my pattern didn't work? Is it the fact i missed out the \ when defining my full stop?

Comment: Sorry being lazy, just tested it with the \ and my rule worked. Thanks again.

Comment: For more generic usage, could be ^[\w,\s-]+\.[A-Za-z]+$  which will match all extensions which have at least 1 char.  This would now accept a file such as web.config

Comment: I don't this will work if the file is named something.mp4

Comment: Why accepting extensions with exactly 3 characters and and no numbers?

Comment: @yannicuLar because the question asks to match extensions with 3 *letters*, not *characters*. It's trivial to adapt the extension part to your needs, eg `[a-zA-Z0-9]{2,4}`

Comment: Ran into that too, so I posted my own answer for DDG-ers.

Comment: Watch out, some files have no `.` or multiple `.`'s

Answer (score 22):

This question was asked specifically to allow **a three letter extension**.

For anyone coming from DuckDuckGo like me (yes, you shouldn't use Google :p), this regex tests for valid filenames and file paths on Windows, Unix and macOS:

```
^[^<>:;,?"*|/]+$
```

or even

```
^[^~)('!*<>:;,?"*|/]+$
```

Note: On Windows, `\`is not allowed in filenames, but the above regex works for checking valid paths on Windows. Include `\\` between the brackets `^[...]+$` if you want it to check for valid filenames and not checking paths.

Comment: Note that on Windows ; and , are valid filename characters so it become: ^[^</*?"\\>:|]+$