# How can I test if a string refers to a file or directory? with regular expressions? in python?

Tags: python, regex, file-management

so I'm writting a generic backup application with `os` module and `pickle` and far I've tried the code below to see if something is a file or directory (based on its string input and not its physical contents).

```
import os, re

def test(path):
    prog = re.compile("^[-\w,\s]+.[A-Za-z]{3}$")
    result = prog.match(path)
    if os.path.isfile(path) or result:
        print "is file"
    elif os.path.isdir(path):
        print "is directory"
    else: print "I dont know"
```

**Problems**

```
test("C:/treeOfFunFiles/")
is directory
test("/beach.jpg")
I dont know
test("beach.jpg")
I dont know
test("/directory/")
I dont know
```

**Desired Output**

```
test("C:/treeOfFunFiles/")
is directory
test("/beach.jpg")
is file
test("beach.jpg")
is file
test("/directory/")
is directory
```

**Resources**

- [Test filename with regular expression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6768779/test-filename-with-regular-expression)
- [Python RE library](http://docs.python.org/py3k/howto/regex.html)
- [Validating file types by regular expression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/374930/validating-file-types-by-regular-expression)

what regular expression should I be using to tell the difference between what might be a `file` and what might be a `directory`? or is there a different way to go about this?

Comment: There are built-ins for this kind of thing.  Also, you generally want to avoid using regular expressions to manipulate path names, too.  They are not only locale dependent (e.g. the yen character in Japan as a path delimiter), but os dependent as well.

Comment: I think you're conflating two separate issues.  Regular expressions won't tell you whether a file is a directory or a regular file.  You need to use `os.path` instead.  See this [solution](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/82831/how-do-i-check-if-a-file-exists-using-python)

Comment: Also, what if I have a directory called `/beach.jpg`?

Comment: @Joel then you should be absolutely ashamed you have such a ridiculously far out naming convention that defies all laws of logic and regex classification systems ;)

Comment: @JonClements: I don't, but I was trying to point out the issues with using regular expressions to identify filesystem objects ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In a character class, if present and meant as a hyphen, the `-` needs to either be the first/last character, or escaped `\-` so change `"^[\w-,\s]+\.[A-Za-z]{3}$"` to `"^[-\w,\s]+\.[A-Za-z]{3}$"` for instance.

Otherwise, I think using regex's to determine if something looks like a filename/directory is pointless...

- `/dev/fd0` isn't a file or directory for instance
- `~/comm.pipe` could look like a file but is a named pipe
- `~/images/test` is a symbolic link to a file called '~/images/holiday/photo1.jpg'

Have a look at the `os.path` module which have functions that ask the OS what something is...:

Comment: Thanks +1 rep because you've shown me how to use regex in python :)

Comment: I've slightly modified my original question

Comment: @Killrawr `is_dir = name[-1] in r'\/'` ? So anything that ends in a path separator (either kind), is just treated as a dir, otherwise, you just don't know

Comment: Thanks Jon the output 3 out of 4 it knows what it is but when it gets to something like `/beach.jpg` the output comes back as `I dont know`, wouldn't the RegEx pick up that its a file because it has `.jpg` ??

Comment: @Killrawr well, you could assume that anything that looks like it has an extension is a file, but then on Linux systems, a lot of stuff doesn't have extensions, but are more likely files, while other stuff that look like they could have extensions, could well be special devices/pipes/other... - so you're going to be wrong one way or another, but if you're happy with that - you get to pick which way you want to do it, and on your own back be it!

Answer (score 5):

The `os` module provides methods to check whether or not a path is a file or a directory. It is advisable to use this module over regular expressions.

```
>>> import os
>>> print os.path.isfile(r'/Users')
False
>>> print os.path.isdir(r'/Users')
True
```

Comment: Oh thats even better :) than what I was trying to accomplish lol :)

Comment: It works but `print os.path.isfile(r'/Users')` doesn't work with strings only actual files that can be openned (`open()`).

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. If a file can be 'openned' it exists, otherwise it will throw an exception. You could use a try/except block to test that way.

Comment: My problem is because my application will be reading strings from a command line and the user may want to restore a file, but that file may not exist on the harddrive (only has a hash). The os.path.isfile()` will return `False` (because the file does not yet exist). But +1 rep great answer :) learn something new every day

Answer (score 4):

This might help someone, I had the exact same need and I used the following regular expression to test whether an input string is a directory, file or neither:
for generic file:

```
^(\/+\w{0,}){0,}\.\w{1,}$
```

for generic directory:

```
^(\/+\w{0,}){0,}$
```

So the generated python function looks like :

```
import os, re

def check_input(path):
    check_file = re.compile("^(\/+\w{0,}){0,}\.\w{1,}$")
    check_directory = re.compile("^(\/+\w{0,}){0,}$")
    if check_file.match(path):
        print("It is a file.")
    elif check_directory.match(path):
        print("It is a directory")
    else:
        print("It is neither")
```

Example:

- check_input("/foo/bar/file.xyz") prints -> Is a file
- check_input("/foo/bar/directory") prints -> Is a directory
- check_input("Random gibberish") prints -> It is neither

This layer of security of input may be reinforced later by the os.path.isfile() and os.path.isdir() built-in functions as Mr.Squig kindly showed but I'd bet this preliminary test may save you a few microseconds and boost your script performance.

PS: While using this piece of code, I noticed I missed a huge use case when the path actually contains special chars like the dash "-" which is widely used. To solve this I changed the \w{0,} which specifies the requirement of alphabetic only words with .{0,} which is just a random character. This is more of a workaround than a solution. But that's all I have for now.

Comment: I think you leave "./toto.sh" or "~/stuff" behind though