# Check if a filename is valid

Tags: python

What would be the most conservative way to check if a file-name is valid in Python on all platforms (including mobile platforms like Android, iOS)?

Ex.

this_is_valid_name.jpg -> Valid

**adad.jpg -> Invalid

a/ad -> Invalid

Comment: That one is about file path. If accessible or not. I am concerned with the most general file naming convention across OSes.

Comment: `**adad.jpg` is a valid name e.g. in GNU/Linux: `open('**adad.jpg', 'w')` will create it.

Comment: What is your research about _valid filenames_ on the various platforms you ask for?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The most harsh way to check if a file would be a valid filename on you target OSes is to check it against a list of properly tested filenames.

```
valid = myfilename in ['this_is_valid_name.jpg']
```

Expanding on that, you could define a **set of characters** that you know are allowed in filenames on every platform :

```
valid = set(valid_char_sequence).issuperset(myfilename)
```

But this is not going to be enough, as some OSes [have reserved filenames](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62888/1643772).

You need to **either exclude reserved names** or [create an expression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6768779/test-filename-with-regular-expression) (regexp) matching the OS allowed filename domain, and **test your filename against that, for each target platform.**

AFAIK, Python does not offer such helpers, because it's [Easier to Ask Forgiveness than Permission](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11360858/what-is-the-eafp-principle-in-python). There's a lot of different possible combinations of OSes/filesystems, it's easier to react appropriately when the os raises an exception than to check for a safe filename domain for all of them.

Comment: Please use a set in your first approach :)

Answer (score 1):

I did a function myself. I used @Voo answer as a start and added checks based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31976060/5931672).

```
import re

def is_valid_folder_name(name: str):
    # Define a regular expression pattern to match forbidden characters
    ILLEGAL_NTFS_CHARS = r'[<>:/\\|?*\"]|[\0-\31]'
    # Define a list of forbidden names
    FORBIDDEN_NAMES = ['CON', 'PRN', 'AUX', 'NUL',
                       'COM1', 'COM2', 'COM3', 'COM4', 'COM5',
                       'COM6', 'COM7', 'COM8', 'COM9',
                       'LPT1', 'LPT2', 'LPT3', 'LPT4', 'LPT5',
                       'LPT6', 'LPT7', 'LPT8', 'LPT9']
    # Check for forbidden characters
    match = re.search(ILLEGAL_NTFS_CHARS, name)
    if match:
        raise ValueError(
            f"Invalid character '{match[0]}' for filename {name}")
    # Check for forbidden names
    if name.upper() in FORBIDDEN_NAMES:
        raise ValueError(f"{name} is a reserved folder name in windows")
    # Check for empty name (disallowed in Windows)
    if name.strip() == "":
        raise ValueError("Empty file name not allowed in Windows")
    # Check for names starting or ending with dot or space
    match = re.match(r'^[. ]|.*[. ]$', name)
    if match:
        raise ValueError(
            f"Invalid start or end character ('{match[0]}')"
            f" in folder name {name}"
        )
```

In your example:

```bash
$ is_valid_folder_name('this_is_valid_name.jpg')
$ is_valid_folder_name('**adad.jpg')
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError in is_valid_folder_name(name)
     13     match = re.search(ILLEGAL_NTFS_CHARS, name)
     14     if match:
---> 15         raise ValueError(
     16             f"Invalid character {match[0]} for filename {name}")
     17     # Check for forbidden names

ValueError: Invalid character '*' for filename **adad.jpg
$ is_valid_folder_name('a/ad')
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError in is_valid_folder_name(name)
     13     match = re.search(ILLEGAL_NTFS_CHARS, name)
     14     if match:
---> 15         raise ValueError(
     16             f"Invalid character {match[0]} for filename {name}")
     17     # Check for forbidden names

ValueError: Invalid character '/' for filename a/ad
```

Please, if someone finds I missed something be free to add it or comment!

Answer (score -2):

Related topic is: "Filename Pattern Matching|.

These are the methods and functions available to you:

1. endswith() and startswith() string methods
2. fnmatch.fnmatch()
3. glob.glob()
4. pathlib.Path.glob()

```py
import os
# Get .txt files
for f_name in os.listdir('some_directory'):
    if f_name.endswith('.txt'):
       print(f_name)
```

Simple Filename Pattern Matching Using fnmatch( )

```
import os
import fnmatch
for file_name in os.listdir('some_directory/'):
    if fnmatch.fnmatch(file_name, '*.txt'):
       print(file_name)
```

More Advanced Pattern Matching

```
for filename in os.listdir('.'):
    if fnmatch.fnmatch(filename, 'data_*_backup.txt'):
       print(filename)
```

Filename Pattern Matching Using glob

```
import glob
glob.glob('*.py')
```

OR Code as

```
import glob
for name in glob.glob('*[0-9]*.txt'):
    print(name)
```

OR Match as

```
import glob
for file in glob.iglob('**/*.py', recursive=True):
    print(file)
```

OR Code as

```
from pathlib import Path
p = Path('.')
for name in p.glob('*.p*'):
    print(name)
```